# How to return 401 for REST API call in Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Following is my sample Spring Security configuration.

I want all `/api` to return HTTP 401 code instead of redirecting 302 to login page.

Also I want to keep the redirect feature for old web pages.

```xml
<security:http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api*" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/oldweb*" access="hasRole('USER')" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1" default-target-url="/home"/>    
</security:http>
```

Answer (score 18):

I came to more simpler solution.
In Spring Boot and Java config you just have to register additional entry point in addition to default one. And because all your rest-services resides in "/api" name space, you could use `AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**")` to match necessary requests.

So, final solution is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.exceptionHandling()
                    //Actually Spring already configures default AuthenticationEntryPoint - LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint
                    //This one is REST-specific addition to default one, that is based on PathRequest
                    .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(getRestAuthenticationEntryPoint(), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"));
    }

    private AuthenticationEntryPoint getRestAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it still support Bearer token authentication or does it requires user to authenticate before on a web page?

Comment: @OndřejStašek This only refers to how the authentication fail is treated, it doesn't change the auth methods.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works so directly. The behavior of ExceptionHandlingConfigurer is not exactly what could be expected. I'd to create the DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint by myself, to ensure the apart from adding the HttpStatusEntryPoint for the specified pattern, it was setting the defaultEntryPoint as still the LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint (or my custom one).

Comment: Great answer. I needed something for my spring application to connect a mobile application to. Returning these status codes resolve alot of my issues.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have a custom authentication entry point.

```
public class CustomEntryPoint extends LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final String XML_HTTP_REQUEST = "XMLHttpRequest";
    private static final String X_REQUESTED_WITH = "X-Requested-With";

    public CustomEntryPoint(String loginFormUrl) {
        super(loginFormUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (XML_HTTP_REQUEST.equals(request.getHeader(X_REQUESTED_WITH))) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        } else {
            super.commence(request, response, exception);
        }
    }    
}
```

Finally change your config to this:

```
<security:http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="customEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/api*" access="hasRole('USER')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/oldweb*" access="hasRole('USER')" />

    <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=1" default-target-url="/home"/>

    <beans:bean id="customEntryPoint" class="CustomEntryPoint">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="/login"/>
    </beans:bean>    
</security:http>
```

Comment: Creating a DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint, where you can have patterns and a default handler is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

When `text/html` is not acceptable, return `401`.

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // ...
        final RequestMatcher matcher = new NegatedRequestMatcher(
            new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML));

        http.exceptionHandling()
            .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED), matcher);

    }
}
```